# How to show desktop version on mobile screens, in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to show desktop version on mobile screens on Bootstrap 3? **I don't** want a link to toggle desktop/mobile version. I just want to show desktop version on mobile screens.

To be clear, I want the website to be responsive on tablets, but on `@media screen max-width: 360px` to show desktop version. I know this is weird, but my client want that, and I have no idea why!

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean? What link?  Have you seen examples of sites built with `Bootstrap`?

Comment: Oh yes. I want to be responsive on tablets. Only on mobile screens "@media screen max-width: 360px" to show the desktop version instead.

Comment: How? It will not have enough space.

Comment: Show an example of your desired layout.

Comment: Yes, it will not have enough space, users will have to move the screen right and left, to show the full site. I know it is weird, but my client wants that :)

Comment: What does "desktop version" mean? Full menu? Multiple columns? It varies widely depending on the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do this, you're going to have to dynamically change your viewport tag based on the width of the screen.

The `viewport` meta tag is what makes responsive design possible on mobile devices by forcing the browser to use the `device-width` as the width for the viewport.  By removing this restriction, most mobile devices will lie about their width in order to get the full site.  With javascript you can dynamically change it based on the page width

Start by including the tag in your HTML `head` element:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Then we'll listen to the resize event and change the viewport according to your business rules:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
    var mobileWidth =  (window.innerWidth > 0) ? 
                        window.innerWidth : 
                        screen.width;
    var viewport = (mobileWidth > 360) ?
                    'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' :
                    'width=1200';
    $("meta[name=viewport]").attr('content', viewport);
}).resize();
```

### [Here's a working Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/VXR6v/)

> **Note**: Desktop browsers ignore the viewport tag so this will not have any affect on your development machine.  In order to test these changes, you can open up the chrome debugger tools and emulate a mobile device.

#### Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

---

That all being said, I would work with your user to *advise against this*.
Here's a quick article I just threw up on [Adding a Desktop Mobile Toggle Button](http://www.codingeverything.com/2014/06/DesktopMobileToggle.html)

It's generally not a good idea to prevent the end user from doing something that they want to do. Your first goal should be to develop a site that works well on small devices.  If a user really wants to see a zoomed out view, then you can provide a toggle switch for them at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks, it kind of working, but there's a bug. The first moment it gets the mobile version, then the desktop version, then back to the mobile version, ... etc. The website is animating between the mobile and desktop version.

Comment: @RahmanSharif, grab the updated code.  I was noticing that problem as well. jQuery was using the viewport width as the site width so it would continuously toggle back and forth.  `window.innerWidth` grabs the actual width so it should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can obviously program `lg`, `sm`, and `xs` behave one way and only `md` the other way.

So you will have something like:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lx-12">...<div>
```

Also do not forget about [viewport meta tag](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972). It will somewhat help with rendering on small devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

or modify to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

So the actual width of the page is defined by the `.container`. So, I've never tried this, but rather than a JavaScript modification, I think you should make:

```
@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

It should be 1170px to match col-lg or 970px to match col-md. Make sure the above is BELOW your bootstrap include so that it overrides, and this should work.

Then, make your (col-md or col-lg) and col-xs have the same values column widths and different than your col-sm for tablets, and things should line up, e.g.

```
<div class='col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-12'>full-width tablet, half others</div>
<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-6'>half-width tablet, 1/4 others</div>
<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-6'>half-width tablet, 1/4 others</div>
```

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately this won't work. All of Bootstrap's responsivity is built off performing media queries against the size of the page/viewport, not the `.container` element.  Your fix would keep the mobile version of the website, but just make it so most of it didn't fit on screen. Here's an [example that includes your solution](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/VXR6v/3/show/).  Notice what happens when when you shrink the width of your browser window.

Comment: @KyleMit, what I see when I shrink my browser is what I expected to see...the need to scroll the desktop version. I guess I wasn't understanding that he wanted the phone to "be" 1200px wide and be that zoomed out. So, in that light, a JS solution makes sense.

Comment: Kevin, Here's a [screenshot comparison of the two](http://i.imgur.com/3am4NRF.png).  In yours, the larger container doesn't actually **change** the view to the way a desktop would display.  It just makes a bigger small view.  When you re-adjust the viewport, the page actually pretends to be larger and you get full desktop elements, like those with the class `visible-lg`.

Comment: @KyleMit, again, I'm not seeing anything that I wouldn't expect. As I tried to illustrate with my HTML, if you do it the way I suggested, you would have to put col-xs-* and visible-xs wherever you had your col-lg-* and visible-lg in order for them to look the same. And to your point (because i was conceding), my way may require writing additional media queries for the menu system, etc., which would make it much less convenient than a JavaScript viewport tweak.