# How to force desktop view on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive-design

How do i force desktop view on mobile devices with Bootstrap?

I have tried fixing the `viewport` width to 1024, but still it doesn't work me.

Any Advices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks All,

This code works for me:

```
var viewMode = getCookie("view-mode");
if(viewMode == "desktop"){
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=1024');
}else if (viewMode == "mobile"){
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no');
}
```

Comment: his new question was removed :P

Comment: Where is the getCookie method coming from? I am using React.js

Answer (score 47):

You just need to set the `Viewport`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

Instead of this (Responsive version)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Look at here. Should solve your issue.

[SO - bootstrap-3-desktop-view-on-a-mobile-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405816/bootstrap-3-desktop-view-on-a-mobile-device)

[SO - how-to-show-desktop-version-on-mobile-screens-in-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498517/how-to-show-desktop-version-on-mobile-screens-in-bootstrap-3)

Comment: My Requirement is to Have Responsive page with link at bottom "Desktop Page View".. Clicking that link, my page content should display like Desktop page.    AND  i tried setting Viewport to 1024, but its not working

Comment: This did not work for me. The page still varies in width between devices, so I can't center anything. I am testing with Google Chrome's built in mobile tester

Comment: Why 1024? Could you explain that?

Answer (score 9):

As for me I use this one I set the initial viewport scale to `0.1`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1">
```

Comment: Why does this work?! 

Comment: Working Perfect

Answer (score 1):

- The best way is to either sent content empty i.e.

```
name="viewport" content=""
```

or

- Take a variable to have the screen width so that it can work on all the screen sizes

```
name="viewport" content="width= {screenWidth}"
```