# Force shiny app to display desktop view on mobile devices

Tags: r, mobile, deployment, shiny

I'm deploying a shiny app to shinyapps.io. It's designed to be used with desktop browsers but when accessing the app on a mobile device it changes to mobile view (which is cool but not useful in this case).

Any idea how to force desktop view for shiny apps?

I tried this answer: [How to force desktop view on mobile devices - Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334481/how-to-force-desktop-view-on-mobile-devices-bootstrap) but didn't get it to work.

(No experience in javascript unfortunately...)

Answer (score 8):

That question had what you needed, include the `<meta>` tag in `HTML`:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   HTML('<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">'),

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2]
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Without tag:**

[image]

**After tag:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately, I don't get it to work with shinydashboards. Any idea where and how to include it in dashboards?

Comment: @ceefel
body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$head(
    tags$meta(name = "viewport", content = "width=1600"),
  uiOutput("body"))