# Force desktop view even on mobile

Tags: html, css

I looked at all the other similar questions and couldn't find an answer.
So first of all I'm noob at programming and I just started learning CSS.
I made a page with these codes:

```
<html>
<style>
    body {
    p.Welcome {
      font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
      font-size: 23px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
    section {
      border-radius: 1em;
      padding: 1em;
      position: absolute;
      top: 49%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-right: -50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
</style>
<section>
  <p class="Welcome">hi</p>
  <img src="blablabla whatever image" />
</section>


<html/>
```

And I want to force desktop version even on mobile, like even when I open that page with mobile, the same page must show up with no change in resolution and other stuff.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334481/how-to-force-desktop-view-on-mobile-devices-bootstrap

Comment: your using some front-end framework?

Comment: I tried the answers on the link above but they didn't work. Neither meta portview nor that script. And btw I have no idea what that front-end framework is, I'm just practicing with notepad++ and a browser. lol

Comment: then there is no 'dektop' \ ' browser' view, you only have ONE view

Comment: When I use desktop, everything looks ok but when I open the same page with mobile, things are all messy. I didn't want to spend any time to fix that so I was just looking for a solution to force the same view on mobile (I don't care if that's gonna be zoomed out or even un-zoom-able)

Comment: every browser on every machine, will interpret your html\css differently. Which is a completely different thing from having desktop\mobile versions\views. The above is invalid html, start by learning valid html

Comment: As someone has pointed out, the code you've included at this point is not valid HTML. Each browser handles invalid markup differently, so step one of getting consistent rendering across browsers is to make your markup as valid as possible. To that end, I would suggest starting here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some comments below, just to help you correct some errors in your HTML. You have to understand that errors like this leave a lot up to interpretation of the browser, to which each may use a different engine or different method which can't guarantee uniform results.

Comments Added:

- You should not use empty rule declarations (located under body rule in CSS).
- Always look for closing tags. Try to use maybe Sublime, VS Code, or Atom as they have "problem" notifiers that may help you catch these mistakes when learning. (located under body rule in CSS).
- If your goal is responsiveness, try and stay away from absolute positioning, or you'll have to media query your way to the same results. (located under section rull in CSS).
- Every tag opened must be closed. Especially for compatibility. Every browser will handle these errors differently, so leaving it up to the browser to decide the result, you won't see the same results in every browser (located above body closing tag in HTML).
- When you close HTML tags, the format is `</html>`. Slashes after are for self-closing tags. (located at the end of the document).

To answer your question more directly, it's difficult. You should understand all screens have varying sizes and dimensions and you must design around this, no exceptions. There is no way to force otherwise. If you set an element to have a width of 800px but the screen is 324px wide, you will not fit that element on the screen.

So my answer is that you're looking for a way to get out of designing for responsiveness, and you can't. Yes, it can be a lot of work, but you'll develop habits as you go. Might I recommend [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org) as well, since they've added some excellent challenges to help teach newer practices to make your projects more responsive, as well as fundamentals like box model.

```
<!-- Always specify your DOCTYPE, note that DOCTYPE is case sensitive. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- You should have a head tag -->
<head></head>
<style type="text/css">
  /* You should not use empty rule declarations */ body {}
  /* Always look for closing tags. Try to use maybe Sublime, VS Code, or Atom as they have "problem" notifiers that may help you catch these mistakes when learning. */

  p.Welcome {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }

  section {
    border-radius: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    /* If your goal is responsiveness, try and stay away from absolute positioning, or you'll have to media query your way to the same results. */
    top: 49%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  }
</style>
<!-- Sections are used for giving semantic clarity to your document, so summarize what the section is -->
<section id="welcome">
  <p class="Welcome">hi</p>
  <img src="http://whatever.com/image.jpg" />
</section>
<!-- Every tag opened must be closed. Especially for compatibility. Every browser will handle these errors differently, so leaving it up to the browser to decide the result, you won't see the same results in every browser -->
</body>
<!-- When you close HTML tags, the format is </html>. Slashes after are for self-closing tags. -->

</html>
```

Comment: this is invalid html

Comment: @smith didn't want to totally bombard with too many changes, but you're right. Feel free to suggest any additional edits you feel would be beneficial to OP. Also note I'm on mobile.

Comment: It was really useful, tyvm!! *Hats off*
Just one last question, since you mentioned "stay away from absolute positioning", is there any way to vertically and horizontally center an image? I tried various ways and only this one worked

Comment: My friend, you're about to fall in love with a thing called Flexbox. Seriously, commit yourself to 20-30 challenges a day on freeCodeCamp and you'll get a lot of this context. Remember, you don't know what you don't know until you're taught, so fully self teaching in coding is tough. freeCodeCamp does a great job at putting you on the right path.

Comment: Much appreciated, I wish we had more people like you in Stackoverflow................

Comment: Any comments to improve this answer are welcome rather than blind downvotes. :)