# How to force desktop view on a specific wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, responsive-design, themes

I have a WordPress website, I want to show one of its pages in desktop view even on mobile devices. So my question is how to force desktop view for specific pages on a mobile device (WordPress)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the `meta` tags as discussed here: [SO: How to force desktop view on mobile devices - Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334481/how-to-force-desktop-view-on-mobile-devices-bootstrap)

To change the meta tags for specific pages, you can create a custom page template, or maybe use a plugin (for example: [Meta tag manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-tag-manager/#description))

Maybe you can also force things with custom CSS for that page, by giving the content container (ex. `.entry-content`) some rule like: `min-width: 1024px;`?