# Bootstrap 3 desktop view on a mobile device

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to display Desktop view in mobile view and tablets.i have googled and tried many method but it seems to be not working

[Bootstrap 3 - desktop view on a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405816/bootstrap-3-desktop-view-on-a-mobile-device)

[How to force desktop view on mobile devices - Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334481/how-to-force-desktop-view-on-mobile-devices-bootstrap)

[Bootstrap 3 - desktop view on a mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405816/bootstrap-3-desktop-view-on-a-mobile-device)

[How to show desktop version on mobile screens, in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498517/how-to-show-desktop-version-on-mobile-screens-in-bootstrap-3)

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13995

i tried following code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

Start by including the tag in your HTML head element:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



$(window).resize(function() {
    var mobileWidth =  (window.innerWidth > 0) ? 
                        window.innerWidth : 
                        screen.width;
    var viewport = (mobileWidth > 360) ?
                    'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' :
                    'width=1200';
    $("meta[name=viewport]").attr('content', viewport);
}).resize();
```

Can any one tell how to solve this issue in latest bootstrap version ?
thank you

Update

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(window).resize(function() {
    var mobileWidth =  (window.innerWidth > 0) ? 
                        window.innerWidth : 
                        screen.width;
    var viewport = (mobileWidth > 360) ?
                    'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' :
                    'width=1200';
    $("meta[name=viewport]").attr('content', viewport);
}).resize(); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YZaUXxE8DOi15bstavUZ?p=preview). the meta property value is being changed. and can you you say what is not working for you ( i mean setting meta property or desktop styles)

Comment: @JSantosh.thank you .your link only display loading .for me i want to display desktop view in mobile devices.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not working?"

Comment: @Jacob.when view this page in mobile view mode then it wont display desktop view.

Answer (score 1):

You use two meta tag in head? If so, plaese delete this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

If meta tag is not, enter this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

...and where is your JavaScript code? In head:

```
<script>
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var mobileWidth =  (window.innerWidth > 0) ? 
                        window.innerWidth : 
                        screen.width;
    var viewport = (mobileWidth > 360) ?
                    'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' :
                    'width=1200';
    $("meta[name=viewport]").attr('content', viewport);
}).resize(); 
</script>
```

Comment: @kaKarmacoma.thank you for the answer .i tried that even though it display mobile responsive

Comment: I think your problem is synthax. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @Karmacoma.i have updated my question

Comment: @tester do you want non-responsive stucture or a button while click to change view mode?

Comment: @Karmacoma.both option also ok.even button onclick also ok